# Photran editor slow or hangs

Tags: eclipse-cdt, eclipse-3.6, eclipse-3.5, photran

I have a fairly large fortran90 project in Photran. I find that sometimes the editor just hangs or is very slow. Saving a file or using ctrl+/ for commenting lines seems to trigger this slowness. Any solutions to this?

I do have refactoring turned on as I find it useful to navigate, turning that off seems to help some. Any other solutions?

I am using eclipse-Galileo, photran 5.0 on linux OS. I have jdk 6 as my java environment. Will updating to Helios and a later photran make a difference? Is it easy to update to Helios?

Edit: Just checked TOP, the cpu is working at 100% when I am trying to save a file! And I even have the refactoring turned off.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer to this question from the photran mailing list...

http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/photran/msg01691.html

See the rest of the thread for more information.

The only solution for now seems to be to turn off refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce the issues with Photran refactoring on and off when using the same workspace with different Eclipse versions. I think you have to remove your ~/.eclipse and ~/workspace/.metadata directories and have a fresh start. I have been using the latest Eclipse (Kepler) with Photran refactoring on/off without any issue.

Comment: I had given up on Photran and was back to vim. I will give your idea a try.

Comment: Any luck? I'm even using idb as a debugger on Eclipse and variable autocomplete (CTRL+Space) is working.

Comment: Sorry @wgodoy, I have moved to a different project that did not require Fortran. I will probably be starting another Fortran project later this year, will let you know how that goes